# Filling region of RGB image specified by polygon in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

After finding boundaries of my regions of interest in an RGB image I want to fill them with specific color on the original picture

```
img=imread('I.png');
BW=~im2bw(img,0.5);
B = bwboundaries(a2);
for k = 1:length(B)
   boundary = B{k};

   % here should color everything inside boundary in blue

end
```

What function can I use to do this? I tried also using *imshow()* and than ploting regions on it, but don't know how to save it in the original resolution.

Comment: You might want to upload `I.png` somewhere and link to it in your question. I'd like to add that for the purpose of filling you don't care about the _boundary_ but about the _area_.

Comment: Wait... You already have everything inside the boundary in white in `BW`. You just need to convert `BW` to an RGB image and then set R and G to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on filling with polygon, you can use [`fill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html), but then you might face some problems:

```
img = imread('Prueba.jpg');
figure;
imshow(img)
```

[image]

```
BW = ~im2bw(img, 0.55);
B = bwboundaries(BW);
hold on
for k = 1:length(B)
   boundary = B{k};
   fill(boundary(:, 2), boundary(:, 1), 'b')
end
```

[image]

As shown in this example, there are regions of the image that are surrounded by a boundary but they are actually supposed to be *outside* the boundary.

Instead, in this way you can avoid the issue:

```
imgR = img(:, :, 1);
imgG = img(:, :, 2);
imgB = img(:, :, 3);
imgR(BW) = 0;
imgG(BW) = 0;
imgB(BW) = intmax(class(imgB));
IMG = cat(3, imgR, imgG, imgB);
figure; imshow(IMG)
```

[image]